# If modified since http header does not appear on first hit but appears after the same page is refreshed

Tags: php

The `if-modified-since` HTTP header does not appear on first hit but appears after the same page is refreshed.

I have a webpage where I have added the `if modified since` HTTP header. On first hit I can see only the last modified response header and after I refresh the same page then I am able to see the `if-modified-since` request header.

Is there any reason why `if-modified-since` request is not visible on first load? Also when I navigate to other pages and then come back to the same page which I visited earlier, I do not see the `if-modified-since` request header and is visible only after the same page refresh.

Why is it happening? I mean, if I have already visited that page then why the `if-modified-since` request is not visible? Am I going wrong anywhere?

Comment: I would guess that this has something to with the Cache-Control as well; by default, PHP will instruct the browser to not cache anything.

Comment: I have set the cache control header to public so ideally the browser should cache the page